# If function and scanf function not working together

Tags: c

so I have been trying to write a code that displays different messages if different keys are pressed

It should display "Your hair looks nice" if one of the characters of the string is pressed and display "You look like your mom" if any number of symbol is pessedd (anything other than the array's elements)

what is the issue here?
(Mind the messages in the code I'm trying to stay chill so I picked random messages)
the code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int
main ()
{
  char i,o;
  
  char a[54] =
    { 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'g', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n',
    'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', 'A', 'B', 'C',
    'D',
    'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'G', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S',
    'T',
    'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z'
  };
   
    
    

  if (scanf ("%c", &o) == a[i])
    printf ("Your hair looks nice");

  else
    printf ("You look like your mom");

  return 0;

}
```

Comment: When you get the value `a[i]`, what is the value of `i`? What are you really trying to do? Also, `scanf` doesn't [return](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf#Return_value) what you think it does.

Answer (score 2):

C have a set of [standard character classification](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte#Character_classification) functions, like for example [`isalpha`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/isalpha) to check if a character is a letter or not.

With this you can make your program much simpler, and don't need the array:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(void)
{
    int ch = getc();  // Read one character

    if (isalpha(c))
    {
        puts("Your hair looks nice.");
    }
    else
    {
        puts("You look like your mom!");
    }
}
```

Note that I use the [`getc`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgetc) function to read a character instead. In most cases `scanf` shouldn't really be used for input, it's use is unfortunately more non-trivial than the beginners guides and tutorials make it seem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check all relevant values of `i`. Currently, you don't even assign a single value to `i`, but you need to assign 54 different values in turn.

And of course, you need to call `scanf` only once, not 54 times.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see whether the inputted character is in the array, then you must compare that character with all 54 characters in the array. However, in your posted code, you are only making one comparison. I suggest that you use a `for` loop for doing the 54 comparisons. You can do one comparison per loop iteration.

Here is an example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main( void )
{
    char a[54] = {
        'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'g', 'k', 'l', 'm',
        'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z',
        'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'G', 'K', 'L', 'M',
        'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z'
    };

    char input;

    //get input character
    if ( scanf( "%c", &input ) != 1 )
    {
        fprintf( stderr, "Input error!\n" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    //determine whether input character is in array
    for ( int i = 0; i < 54; i++ )
    {
        if ( a[i] == input )
        {
            printf( "Found character in array.\n" );
            return 0;
        }
    }

    printf( "Did not find character in array.\n" );
    return 0;
}
```

However, in order to determine whether a character is an alphabetical letter, there is a much simpler solution: You can simply call the function [`isalpha`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/isalpha) as demonstrated in one of the other answers.

Answer (score 0):

**From scanf's man page:**

*RETURN VALUE:*

> On success, these functions return the number of input items successfully matched and assigned; this can be fewer than provided for, or even zero, in the event of an early matching failure.

According to this, the statement

```
if (scanf ("%c", &o) == a[i])
```

compares the return value of `scanf`, which in this case would be one `1`(if `scanf` succeeded) to `a[i]`, where `i` is uninitialised and leads to undefined behaviour. As I remember @Fe203 once saying:

> "Leaving variables uninitialised is asking Demon of Hard-To-Find Bugs to co-author your code."

So you ought to first initialise `i`, then iterate through the array, comparing `o` to all the 54 values of `i`.

**Aside:**

You shouldn't be using scanf for user-interactive stuff. It is not supposed to be used as such, and it's quite hard to get right. In this case, consider using `getc` or `getchar` which reads one character at a time.

Or at least, check the return value of `scanf`.

Comment: This is a hw and our professor decided that only <stdio.h> is allowed :D we tried to argue but he said if he didn't explain it then we can't use it. I am still wondering how much can he explain in a 70 hours course. thx for help everyone I will probably spend the weekend searching "How to design ****** in Stdio.

Comment: All the I/O functions can be found in ```stdio.h``` header files. ```getc``` and ```getchar``` too are included in it, but as you can't use them, you'd do well to check the return value of ```scanf```.                                                    Aside: You should forget ```scanf``` exists and read a whole line with ```fgets``` and parse it with ```sscanf```, ```strtol``` etc. It's also a good SO etiquette to accept the answer you found helpful by clicking on the check mark, so whichever one worked for you, accept it.